# upgrade magento 2.2.6 to 2.3.3 PHP requirement incompatible with your PHP version (5.6.33.0)

Tags: magento2.3.3, magento-upgrade

i am upgrading magento version like 
**magento 2.2.6 to magento 2.3.3** 
and my php version is 7.2 
but still not run command

[image]

and my PHP CLI version

anyone facing this issue?
**which command needed in magento 2.3.3 upgrade?** 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: create info.php file and write this code : <?php phpinfo(); ?> and run this file in browser and check which php version display there

Comment: 7.2 version same

Comment: What is your composer version ?

Comment: Please try to run **composer -v** and check

Comment: @KishanSavaliya i have checked php -v and showing 5.3 and but my server team told me check this way.. `/hsphere/shared/php72/bin/php-cli -v`

Comment: First check which PHP version is used by composer using composer -vvv about if find PHP is 5.~ then this link might help you to change PHP version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986139/how-to-change-php-version-used-by-composer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to run below command

```
php71 /usr/local/bin/composer.phar require magento/project-community-edition=2.3.3 --no-update
```

You can use below line instead of `composer`

```
php71 /usr/local/bin/composer.phar
```

**Update**

Try to run commands in below sequence to upgrade Magento version from 2.2.6 to 2.3.3

```
- php71 bin/magento maintenance:enable
- cp composer.json composer.json.bak
- php71 /usr/local/bin/composer.phar remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update
- php71 /usr/local/bin/composer.phar require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.3 --no-update
- php71 /usr/local/bin/composer.phar require --dev allure-framework/allure-phpunit:~1.2.0 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.14.0 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10 magento/magento-coding-standard:~3.0.0 magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework:2.4.5 pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 phpmd/phpmd:@stable phpunit/phpunit:~6.5.0 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer:~3.4.0 --sort-packages --no-update
- php71 /usr/local/bin/composer.phar remove --dev sjparkinson/static-review fabpot/php-cs-fixer --no-update
- rm -rf update
- mv temp_dir/update .
- rm -rf temp_dir
- php71 /usr/local/bin/composer.phar update
- php71 bin/magento cache:clean
- php71 bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Ref [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html)

Hope this will help you!